# How to override import_data() method from orm

Tags: odoo

I am using OpenERP 6.1. I want to override method import_data() from osv.orm.BaseModel class.
This class have _name attribute is None

Comment: just inherit and override simple

Comment: Hi senthilnathang, i have inherited this method but original method executes. I have inherited it as following                       from osv import osv, fields
from osv.orm import BaseModel

class orm_import(BaseModel):
    
    _register = False
    _name = None
    _table = None

    def import_data(self, cr, uid, fields, datas, mode='init', current_module='', noupdate=False, context=None, filename=None):
        #My code here
        
orm_import()

Comment: Add this code to your question. I would be much easier to read and your question would be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is called a monkey patch and i highly warn you on this. there can be so many side effects --> not controllable.

if you have some business models (e.g. extended res.partner), on which you want to use another import_data routine, then do it the normal way by inheriting and overriding the method.

but if you want to override it globally, you have to use a monkey patch. but that is NOT RECOMMENDABLE.